# Remove duplicate rows from a pandas dataframe: Case Insenstive comparison

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I want to remove duplicate rows from the dataframe based on values in two columns: `Column1` and `Column2`

If `dataframe` is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ["'cat'", "'toy'", "'cat'"],
                   'Column2': ["'bat'", "'flower'", "'bat'"],
                   'Column3': ["'xyz'", "'abc'", "'lmn'"]})
```

On using:

```
result_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Column1', 'Column2'], keep='first')
print(result_df)
```

I get:

```
  Column1   Column2 Column3
0   'cat'     'bat'   'xyz'
1   'toy'  'flower'   'abc'
```

But using same code for `dataframe` (Cat and Bat cases changed)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ["'Cat'", "'toy'", "'cat'"],
                   'Column2': ["'Bat'", "'flower'", "'bat'"],
                   'Column3': ["'xyz'", "'abc'", "'lmn'"]})
```

I get:

```
  Column1   Column2 Column3
0   'Cat'     'Bat'   'xyz'
1   'toy'  'flower'   'abc'
2   'cat'     'bat'   'lmn'
```

Expected Output:

```
  Column1   Column2 Column3
0   'cat'     'bat'   'xyz'
1   'toy'  'flower'   'abc'
```

How can this comparison be done case insensitively?

Comment: it seems that there is no built in way of doing this, to common practice seems to be to case your column first and then drop_duplicates

Comment: @Nullman but i want to preserve cases..

Comment: before you drop the duplicates, I think you can convert the string to lower case. E.g. `df['Column1'] = [c1.lower() for c1 in df['Column1']]` for `Column1`. Do the same to other columns.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured it out. Create new uppercase columns and then use them to remove the duplicates. Once done, drop the uppercase columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ["'Cat'", "'toy'", "'cat'"],
                       'Column2': ["'Bat'", "'flower'", "'bat'"],
                       'Column3': ["'xyz'", "'abc'", "'lmn'"]})

df['Column1_Upper'] = df['Column1'].astype(str).str.upper()
df['Column2_Upper'] = df['Column2'].astype(str).str.upper()
```

This gives:

```
+---+---------+----------+---------+---------------+---------------+
|   | Column1 | Column2  | Column3 | Column1_Upper | Column2_Upper |
+---+---------+----------+---------+---------------+---------------+
| 0 | 'Cat'   | 'Bat'    | 'xyz'   | 'CAT'         | 'BAT'         |
| 1 | 'toy'   | 'flower' | 'abc'   | 'TOY'         | 'FLOWER'      |
| 2 | 'cat'   | 'bat'    | 'lmn'   | 'CAT'         | 'BAT'         |
+---+---------+----------+---------+---------------+---------------+
```

Finally, run the below to drop the duplicates and created columns.

```
result_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Column1_Upper', 'Column2_Upper'], keep='first')
result_df.drop(['Column1_Upper', 'Column2_Upper'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(result_df)
```

This gives:

```
+-----------------------------+
|   Column1   Column2 Column3 |
+-----------------------------+
| 0   'Cat'     'Bat'   'xyz' |
| 1   'toy'  'flower'   'abc' |
+-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the dataframe to lower case and then apply your solution.

Your dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ["'Cat'", "'toy'", "'cat'"],
                   'Column2': ["'Bat'", "'flower'", "'bat'"],
                   'Column3': ["'xyz'", "'abc'", "'lmn'"]})

print(df)

  Column1   Column2 Column3
0   'Cat'     'Bat'   'xyz'
1   'toy'  'flower'   'abc'
2   'cat'     'bat'   'lmn'
```

Then apply lower string.

```
result_df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower()).drop_duplicates(subset=['Column1', 'Column2'], keep='first')

print(result_df)
  Column1   Column2 Column3
0   'cat'     'bat'   'xyz'
1   'toy'  'flower'   'abc'
```

Then filter df for upper case.

```
df.loc[result_df.index]

  Column1   Column2 Column3
0   'Cat'     'Bat'   'xyz'
1   'toy'  'flower'   'abc'
```

Answer (score 1):

First, convert all the string values to lowercase to make them case insensitive using the following line:

```
df[['Column1', 'Column2']] = df[['Column1', 'Column2']].applymap(lambda x: x.lower())
```

You will get the output as follows.

```
    Column1   Column2  Column3 
0   'cat'     'bat'   'xyz'
1   'toy'  'flower'   'abc'
2   'cat'     'bat'   'lmn'
```

Now apply the drop duplicates function.

```
result_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Column1', 'Column2'], keep='first')
print(result_df)
```

```
  Column1   Column2 Column3
0   'cat'     'bat'   'xyz'
1   'toy'  'flower'   'abc'
```

reference: [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)